# c++ edit box goes behind main window

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

i created a edit box but it doesn't show on the window. it shows if the window is not full screen. if it is full screen the edit box goes behind it. here is the function for the edit box

```
HWND editbox=CreateWindowA("EDIT", NULL, 
                      WS_VISIBLE | WS_EX_TOPMOST | WS_BORDER | ES_LEFT, 
                      87, 81, 150, 17, 
                      hWnd, 
                      (HMENU)5, hInstance, NULL);
```

i don't know why it does that i set it to `WS_EX_TOPMOST` and it still goes behind it.  i used directx 9 to make my program in full screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All `WS_EX_**` styles should be passed as the **first** argument of `CreateWindowEx`, not the third of `CreateWindow`. This probably causes the problem. Use `CreateWindowExA` instead.
All the arguments in `CreateWindowEx` remain the same, there's just one additional parameter at the beginning.

```
HWND editbox=CreateWindowExA(WS_EX_TOPMOST, "EDIT", NULL, 
                  WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | ES_LEFT, 
                  87, 81, 150, 17, 
                  hWnd, 
                  (HMENU)5, hInstance, NULL);
```

**EDIT:** I know what was wrong. You forgot the WS_CHILD style in the third argument. It is needed so Windows knows that this is a child window.

```
HWND editbox=CreateWindowA("EDIT", NULL,
              WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | ES_LEFT,
              87, 81, 150, 17,
              hWnd,
              (HMENU)5, hInstance, NULL);
```

Comment: I have posted the working code under my edit. Are you sure that your code looks the same?

Comment: How do you know that the window is __behind__ the parent? Maybe it doesn't show at all? BTW, I didn't notice before that you're using DirectX. I don't have any solution then, I have never worked with DX ;/

Comment: i searched and when my program in full screen there is no way i can display any window over it

Answer (score 2):

HWND editbox=CreateWindowA("EDIT", NULL,
              WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | ES_LEFT,
              87, 81, 150, 17,
              hWnd,
              (HMENU)5, hInstance, NULL);

WS_CHILD is required if you want to display the new control atop a window...